# Uncaught Error: INDEX_SIZE_ERR

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, canvas, drawimage

I am drawing on a canvas with the following line:

**ctx.drawImage(compositeImage, 0, 0, image.width, image.height, i, j, scaledCompositeImageWidth, scaledCompositeImageHeight);**

This code has executed error free on Safari, Chrome, Firefox (and even IE using google's excanvas library).  However, a recent update to Chrome now throws the following error:

**Uncaught Error: INDEX_SIZE_ERR: DOM Exception 1**

This code often positions part or all of the drawn image OFF the canvas, anyone got any idea what's going on here?

Answer (score 20):

Is `compositeImage` pointing at a valid (fully loaded) image?

I've seen this exception happen if you try to draw the image before it has loaded.

E.g.

```
img = new Image();
img.src = '/some/image.png';
ctx.drawImage( img, ..... ); // Throws error
```

Should be something like

```
img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
  ctx.drawImage( img, .... );
};
img.src = '/some/image.png';
```

To ensure the image has loaded.

Comment: In my case i was trying to copy image with more size that it had - i.e. my sprite image had 100px, and i tried to copy 25px starting from 80px pos, when i fixed image size to be 105px all started to work.

Answer (score 8):

**Why?**

It happens if you draw the image before it is loaded because that is what the html5 2dcontext draft specifies for interpreting the first argument of `drawImage()`:

> If one of the sw or sh  arguments is zero, the implementation must raise an INDEX_SIZE_ERR exception.

*sw, sh being source-image width and height*

@jimr's answer is good, just thought it would be relevant to add this here.

Answer (score 3):

Another cause for this error is, the dimensions of the source image are too large; they extend beyond the actual image dimensions. When this occurs, you'll see this error in IE, but not in Chrome or Firefox.

Say you have a 150x150 image:

```
var imageElement = ...;
```

Then if you try to draw it using larger source dimensions:

```
var sourceX = 0;
var sourceY = 0;
var sourceWidth = 200; // Too big!
var sourceHeight = 200; // Too big!
canvasContext.drawImage(imageElement, 
   sourceX, sourceY, sourceWidth, sourceHeight, // Too big! Will throw INDEX_SIZE_ERR
   destX, destY, destWidth, destHeight);
```

This will throw INDEX_SIZE_ERR on IE. (The latest IE being IE11 at the time of this writing.)

The fix is simply constraining the source dimensions:

```
var sourceWidth = Math.min(200, imageElement.naturalWidth);
var sourceHeight = Math.min(200, imageElement.naturalHeight);
```

malloc4k's answer alluded to this, however, he suggested it was because image.width was zero. I added this new answer because image width being zero is not necessarily the cause of the error on IE.

Answer (score 1):

Due to my experience, INDEX_SIZE_ERR in IE (even version 10) is likely to happen when you are operating on canvas that has been manipulated with `drawImage()` with wrong clip size.

And if you loaded your image dynamically, then it is likely that values of
`image.width`  and `image.height` are `==0`, so you are invoking

```
ctx.drawImage(compositeImage, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
```

In my case the solution (that worked) was to use `image.naturalWidth` and `image.naturalHeight` instead.