# Uncaught Error: INDEX_SIZE_ERR: DOM Exception 1, getImageData

Tags: javascript, html

I am using following code to convert my image into grey scale, on local machine it is fine but when I deploy the same on server it passes **Uncaught Error: INDEX_SIZE_ERR: DOM Exception 1**  I wonder is it due to different domain, I am not sure but problem is due to "getImageData". Also, this problem is only on chrome.

I have read lot of posts and tried a lot, but seems like nothing working for me.

Thanks in Advance...

```
function grayscale(img) {
         var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
         var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
         var imgObj = new Image();
         imgObj.src = img;
         canvas.width = imgObj.width;
         canvas.height = imgObj.height;
         ctx.drawImage(imgObj, 0, 0);
         var imgPixels = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
         for (var y = 0; y < imgPixels.height; y++) {
         for (var x = 0; x < imgPixels.width; x++) {
         var i = (y * 4) * imgPixels.width + x * 4;
         var avg = (imgPixels.data[i] + imgPixels.data[i + 1] + imgPixels.data[i + 2]) / 3;
                    imgPixels.data[i] = avg;
                    imgPixels.data[i + 1] = avg;
                    imgPixels.data[i + 2] = avg;
                }
            }
            ctx.putImageData(imgPixels, 0, 0, 0, 0, imgPixels.width, imgPixels.height);
            return canvas.toDataURL();
        }
```

Comment: did you try an image from the same domain??

Comment: Hi, Yes, images are in same domains, hosted by same service, moreover, when I gave images locally, and then host it on server the problem is same.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Drawing_Graphics_with_Canvas#Compatibility_With_Apple_.3Ccanvas.3E --- could this be a reason??

Comment: . . Duplicate of <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923564/uncaught-error-index-size-err> (among others). . . tl;dr: The image is not fully loaded when you try to call "drawImage".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Uncaught Error: INDEX\_SIZE\_ERR](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923564/uncaught-error-index-size-err)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had similar issue in IE9, IE10.

I would suggest using, in your case ( creating image object dynamically ):

```
imgObj.naturalWidth;
imgObj.naturalHeight;
```

instead of

```
imgObj.width;
imgObj.height;
```

Answer (score 3):

This works fine for me

```
// img is HTMLImageElement
function makeGreyScale(img) {
  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var imgObj = new Image();
  imgObj.src = img.src;
  imgObj.onload = function(){
    canvas.width = imgObj.width;
    canvas.height = imgObj.height;
    ctx.drawImage(imgObj, 0, 0);
    var imgPixels = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    for(var y = 0; y < imgPixels.height; y++){
      for(var x = 0; x < imgPixels.width; x++){
        var i = (y * 4) * imgPixels.width + x * 4;
        var avg = (imgPixels.data[i] + imgPixels.data[i + 1] + imgPixels.data[i + 2]) / 3;
        imgPixels.data[i] = avg;
        imgPixels.data[i + 1] = avg;
        imgPixels.data[i + 2] = avg;
      }
    }
    ctx.putImageData(imgPixels, 0, 0, 0, 0, imgPixels.width, imgPixels.height);
    img.src= canvas.toDataURL();
  };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you are not calling the script using window.load and rather using on DOM load.  I ran into the same problem using the grayscale script.  Here's the code that works for me:

```
$(window).load(function(){

    imageColorize();
});


//Black and white images to color
function imageColorize(){

    // Fade in images so there isn't a color "pop" document load and then on window load
    $(".colorize img").fadeIn(500);

    // clone image
    $('.colorize img').each(function(){
        var el = $(this);
        el.css({"position":"absolute"}).wrap("<div class='img_wrapper' style='display: inline-block'>").clone().addClass('img_grayscale').css({"position":"absolute","z-index":"998","opacity":"0"}).insertBefore(el).queue(function(){
            var el = $(this);
            el.parent().css({"width":this.width,"height":this.height});
            el.dequeue();
        });
        this.src = grayscale(this.src);
    });

    // Fade image
    $('.colorize img').mouseover(function(){
        $(this).parent().find('img:first').stop().animate({opacity:1}, 1000);
    });
    $('.colorize .img_grayscale').mouseout(function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({opacity:0}, 1000);
    });

}

// Grayscale w canvas method
function grayscale(src){
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var imgObj = new Image();
    imgObj.src = src;
    canvas.width = imgObj.width;
    canvas.height = imgObj.height;
    ctx.drawImage(imgObj, 0, 0);
    var imgPixels = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    for(var y = 0; y < imgPixels.height; y++){
        for(var x = 0; x < imgPixels.width; x++){
            var i = (y * 4) * imgPixels.width + x * 4;
            var avg = (imgPixels.data[i] + imgPixels.data[i + 1] + imgPixels.data[i + 2]) / 3;
            imgPixels.data[i] = avg;
            imgPixels.data[i + 1] = avg;
            imgPixels.data[i + 2] = avg;
        }
    }
    ctx.putImageData(imgPixels, 0, 0, 0, 0, imgPixels.width, imgPixels.height);
    return canvas.toDataURL();
}
```