# image.onload fires before image is completely loaded

Tags: javascript, html, mobile-safari, html5-canvas, android-browser

I'm making a game using javascript + canvas.
I use the code below to ensure

```
var imgLoaded = 0;
var imgToLoad = multiImgs;
var onImgLoad = function()
{
   imgLoaded++;
   if(imgLoaded == imgToLoad)
   {
      ctx.drawImage()
   }
}

for(var i = 0; i < multiImgs; i++)
{
  images[i] = new Image();
  images[i].onload = onImgLoad();
  images[i].src = 'images/'+i+'.png';
}
```

This code at times works fine, esp. when the images are cached. However, when loading for the first time, at times, it gives INDEX_SIZE_ERR: DOM Exception 1
which I found is due to height & width of image not being available as suggested by Quickredfox in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923564/uncaught-error-index-size-err)... but then here drawImage is called only when all the images are loaded?
The error primarily occurs in mobile devices

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to provide a *reference* to the load handler. Otherwise, the function executes immediately. Use:

```
images[i].onload = onImgLoad;
```

Comment: Thanks. Gross oversight on my part!

Comment: I was wondering why my method got executed right away. Thank you for this solution! As for someone new to JavaScript this isn't that obvious, though I understand it because of your comment :)