# Problems with jQuery greyscale.js and basic slider

Tags: jquery, slider, grayscale

Hoping someone will take pity on me and can offer some advice - my knowledge of jQuery is limited at best, and I only really know the basic stuff (how to apply CSS classes etc) than writing / debugging the code myself.

I'm working on a website for a friend's wedding (an engagement present from me) and I'm having issues with trying to get greyscale.js and the basic slider to play nicely. As soon as I add the slider function, the greyscale effect breaks.

The site -  still very much in development so not tested in any PC browsers, is here - http://www.elandsebswedding.co.uk/wp-content/themes/weddingTheme/index.html

When the page loads, you can see the images in colour and then grey out - but they just won't return to colour on mouseover.

Any advice - or suggestions of another plugin that will achieve the same thing - would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

---

There seems to be an error with greyscale.js - firebug is saying index or size is greater than allowed amount and highlighting the below as the issue?

imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, width, height);

---

UPDATE

Ok - seem to have made slight progress - the fact that there wasn't a height / width on the image in the sliders (venue section) seemed to be causing an issue.

Comment: you get the following error in your greyscale.js file (in chrome):
Uncaught Error: INDEX_SIZE_ERR: DOM Exception 1.

Comment: Googled a bit, and found out, that the above mentioned error might occur, when an image is drawn but not fully loaded. Look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923564/uncaught-error-index-size-err). My console also states, that the image `tbc.jpg` is not loaded. Might have to do with that...

Comment: Ok - I've removed the TBC images and it seems the same thing is happening. When I remove the slider function - it all works :S

Answer (score 0):

Missing height / width attribute on slider was causing the issue. I suspect that the greyScale plugin doesn't play nicely with a responsive design...